# scrape a JS-Rendered, JSON data using R

Tags: javascript, r, elasticsearch, httr, rselenium

I'm trying to download some contents/data from a webpage with javascript rendered contents in R, After some searches I found a different solution but can't get the exact required output,

here is one of the way so far I have tried

```
library(httr)
library(rjson)

link <- "https://rod.pulse.gop.pk/details_page.html?I=740287512"
response <- httr::POST(
  url = "https://rodb.pulse.gop.pk/registry_index_2/_search",
  httr::add_headers(
    .headers = c(
      "Authorization" = "'Basic ' + btoa('elastic:qZM2ov-qIa=UXr6+Gx8b')",  
      "Content-Type" = "application/json"
    )
  ), 
  body = link
)

data <- fromJSON(content(response, as="text"))
```

required data at a glance

```
data <- 
  structure(list(Id = 740287512L, UserId = 13887L, VendorId = 1L, 
                 UserWorkQueMasterId = 740237089L, RegisteredNumber = "310", 
                 JildNumber = "1489", PropertyNumber = "واقع رقبہ  موضع سوہان دیہاتی  اندر حدود  میونسپل کارپوریشن راولپنڈی تحصیل و ضلع راولپنڈی ", 
                 IsApproved = TRUE, IsJildCompleted = FALSE, BahiNumber = NA, 
                 RegistryDate = "1993-01-25", IsActive = TRUE, CreatedDate = "2023-10-23T20:09:19.310000", 
                 ModifiedDate = NA, CreatedBy = 13887L, ModifiedBy = NA, TehsilId = 112L, 
                 MauzaId = 0L, Address = "N/A", IsExported = NA, Area = "0-8-0-0", 
                 RegistryValue = 128000, RegistryExportImg = "cfe958064b6c79b71e03350b5394f32a", 
                 NonNullFCount = NA, NullFCount = NA, RegistryTypeId = 5L, 
                 MauzaName = NA, RegistryParties = list(structure(list(Id = 18595212:18595213, 
                                                                       Name = c("محمد یسین ", "چوہدری رحمت "
                                                                       ), SpouseName = c("شمس الدین ", "چوہدری الله دین "
                                                                       ), CNIC = c("21134087515", "0"), RegistryPartiesTypeId = 1:2, 
                                                                       CraetedDate = c("2023-10-23T20:09:19.310000", "2023-10-23T20:09:19.310000"
                                                                       ), ModifiedDate = c(NA, NA), CreatedBy = c(13887L, 13887L
                                                                       ), ModifiedBy = c(NA, NA), VendorId = c(1L, 1L), SequenceNumber = 1:2, 
                                                                       RegistryExportImg = c("b17f19516a4fc8742aa21ce8bf0340b4", 
                                                                                             "89c79a6b93dde25904088ce129b1a22a")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)), 
                 RegistryType = "بیع", Tehsil = "راولپنڈی"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")
```

all the data is publicly available and any efficient solution would be acceptable